# Error when memcached is down

Tags: python, memcached

I'm trying to catch an error in memcached when this one is down with python:

```
import memcache
import socket
mc = memcache.Client(['127.0.0.1:11211'], debug=1)

try:
    print mc.get('gfdsgf')
except socket.error:
   print 'error'
```

But I still have this error in my console:

```
MemCached: MemCache: inet:127.0.0.1:11211: connect: Connection refused.  Marking dead.
None
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is not really an error that you can catch this is just a log, and it's displayed because you have the debug parameter to 1, so turn off the debug parameter. And as you can see you still get None from your print that mean your key doesn't exist

Try something like that:

```
import memcache
mc = memcache.Client(['127.0.0.1:11211'], debug=0)
try:
    print mc.get('gfdsgf')
except (mc.MemcachedKeyTypeError, mc.MemcachedKeyNoneError,
                    TypeError, mc.MemcachedKeyCharacterError,
                    mc.MemcachedKeyError, mc.MemcachedKeyLengthError,
                    mc.MemcachedStringEncodingError):
   print 'error'
```